# TListView Column Sort (Sort by first two columns)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using Delphi 2010 and TListView to list Names and other data. The first two columns is the Last Name & First Name

> Caption = Last Name
>   SubItems[0] = First Name

How do I sort the ListView by these two columns? These will only be the columns the Listview will be sorted by and I would like to always keep the sort as such (when adding, editing, deleting items)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'd use virtual mode. Don't make the GUI control be your data structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `SortType` to 'stBoth', and implement an `OnCompare` event handler. Example:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
var
  S1, S2: string;
begin
  S1 := Item1.Caption;
  if Item1.SubItems.Count > 0 then
    S1 := S1 + Item1.SubItems[0];
  S2 := Item2.Caption;
  if Item2.SubItems.Count > 0 then
    S2 := S2 + Item2.SubItems[0];

  Compare := CompareText(S1, S2);
end;
```