# Simple TListView Save and load to and from file (Saving just the column string values)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using Delphi 2010 and I searched the internet and found a few examples, but neither of them worked. I am using it may because of 2010 and unicode? Anyway......

I am looking for two routines to do a simple save and load to and from file for a TListView.
I am only interested in saving the string values in each column. i.e. the caption and the subitems. I am not interested in saving the layout or any objects.

```
procedure SaveToFile(const FileName: string);
procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
```

Comment: Now you reached the time when you'll realize that [you should keep data separated from a GUI control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057886/tlistview-column-sort-sort-by-first-two-columns#comment21171040_15057886).

Comment: @TLama is right, you really don't want to make a visual control be your primary data structure.

Comment: It is just for a simple destop app, which will not hold much more than a couple hundred items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something very crude. It uses a rather limited tab-delimited text format. The contents are not allowed to contain inline tab characters. I've also implemented no error checking whatsoever on the load function. I'm sure you can add that.

```
uses
  ComCtrls, Types, StrUtils;

procedure ListViewSaveToFile(ListView: TListView; const FileName: string);

  procedure AddTextToLine(var Line: string; const Text: string);
  begin
    Line := Line + Text + #9;
  end;

  procedure MoveCompletedLineToList(const Strings: TStringList; var Line: string);
  begin
    Strings.Add(System.Copy(Line, 1, Length(Line)-1));//remove trailing tab
    Line := '';
  end;

var
  Strings: TStringList;
  LatestLine: string;
  i, j: Integer;

begin
  LatestLine := '';

  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to ListView.Items.Count-1 do begin
      AddTextToLine(LatestLine, ListView.Items[i].Caption);
      for j := 0 to ListView.Items[i].SubItems.Count-1 do begin
        AddTextToLine(LatestLine, ListView.Items[i].SubItems[j]);
      end;
      MoveCompletedLineToList(Strings, LatestLine);
    end;
    Strings.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ListViewLoadFromFile(ListView: TListView; const FileName: string);
var
  Strings: TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  Fields: TStringDynArray;
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    ListView.Clear;
    for i := 0 to Strings.Count-1 do begin
      Fields := SplitString(Strings[i], #9);
      Item := ListView.Items.Add;
      Item.Caption := Fields[0];
      for j := 1 to high(Fields) do begin
        Item.SubItems.Add(Fields[j]);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution, using a TStringList and Name/Value pairs, which seems to work just fine. I store the Item caption in the name, and all the sub columns in the value, then I just parse the value for the individual subitems

```
procedure LoadFromFile(AListView: TListView; AFileName: string);
var
 I : Integer;
 SL: TStringList;
 Item: TListItem;
 Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5: String;
begin
  SL:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    AListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
    AListView.Items.Clear;
    for I:=  0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    begin
     Item:= AlistView.Items.Add;
     Item.Caption:= SL.Names[I];
     parseValue(SL.ValueFromIndex[I], Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col0);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col1);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col2);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col3);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col4);
     Item.SubItems.Add(Col5);
    end;
    AListView.Items.EndUpdate;
  finally
   SL.Free;
  end;
end;

    procedure SaveToFile(AListView: TListView; AFileName: string);
    var
     I: Integer;
     SL: TStringList;
    begin
     SL:= TStringList.Create;
     for I := 0 to AListView.Items.Count - 1 do
     begin
      SL.Add(AlistView.Items[I].Caption + '=' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[0] + ',' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[1] + ',' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[2] + ',' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[3] + ',' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[4] + ',' +
             AlistView.Items[I].SubItems[5])
     end;
     try
      SL.SaveToFile(AFileName);
     finally
       SL.Free;
     end;
    end;

 procedure parseValue(AValue: String; var Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5: String);
 var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
  L: TStringList;
 begin
  //create a temporary list to store the data parts in
  L:= TStringList.Create;
  try
  //iterate through the length of the string
  for I:= 1 to length(AValue) do
  begin
   //if the char is not a comma, append it to S
   if AValue[I] <> ',' then
    S:= S + AValue[I]
   else
   // if char is a comma, add S to temporary list and reset S
   begin
    L.Add(S);
    S:= '';
   end;
  end;
  //add the last string to temporary list
  L.Add(S);
  //assign the items in temporary list to variables to be passed back 
  Col0:= L[0];
  Col1:= L[1];
  Col2:= L[2];
  Col3:= L[3];
  Col4:= L[4];
  Col5:= L[5];
  finally
   L.Free;
  end;
 end;
```

Comment: What are you going to do when you change the number of columns. You should not hard code that. And why re-invent SplitString.

Comment: Im not changing the number of columns, and I wasn't aware of split string. I will use your solution, I was just trying to see if I can write something myself. Learning

Comment: No probs. Your solution is quite fine though! Don't get me wrong. I was offering criticism that was hopefully constructive. Don't forget to add error checking though in case the user has messed with the contents of the file between save and load.